# Fastest and most efficient way to write if something exists

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, echo

Here is my code that I want to shorten:

```
if($array != null) {
    if($array[0] === 1) {
        echo $array[1];
    }
}
```

here is what im trying to accomplish: execution speed/performance (fastest), and the shortest way to write it.

here is what i tried:

```
echo ($array[0] === 1 ? $array[1] : null)
```

but that does not include the `if($array != null)`. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ternary statement like this:

```
echo ($array[0] === 1) ? $array[1] : NULL ;
```

EDIT: based on update question the OP wants to use a nested ternary (*not recommended* due to possible maintenance issues). Here is that nest:

```
(isset($array) && !empty($array)) ? (($array[0] === 1) ? $array[1] : NULL) : NULL
```

If the array is not empty, check to see if `$array[0]` is equal to 1. If it is output `$array[1]`, else output nothing. If the array is empty return `NULL`.